# Making text fields stretch in two separate subreports

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have a main subreport, that contains two similar subreports placed next to each other.
These two similar subreports both contain a text field in the detail band. Detail band is set to stretch.
My problem is when one of the text fields contain a long text, and the other is not,there will be a "gap" on side with the short text. The text field with the short text should stretch also.
[image]

Is there a way to achive this while maintaining two separate subreports? Or do I have create one subreport from the two, putting both text fields into one subreport?

Here's a simplifeid version of the main subreport, and the two subreport containing the text fields.

Main report:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.6.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.6.0  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Invoice" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="255" columnWidth="595" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" resourceBundle="InvoiceBundle" uuid="4328d8a4-e5d5-4d7d-9fba-b42407325799">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.5000000000000007"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="develop trunk"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <style name="table">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <parameter name="ID" class="java.lang.Long">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["./"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="DATEFORMAT" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT 1 -- This is a must, because subreports in Detail Band will only show data if the query has result. TODO: Move this supreport into Header Band.]]>
    </queryString>
    <detail>
        <band height="240" splitType="Stretch">
            <frame>
                <reportElement style="table" positionType="Float" x="0" y="140" width="555" height="80" uuid="ee798e27-e04b-46e1-ae6b-b85f881d6878"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <subreport isUsingCache="false">
                    <reportElement style="table" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="300" height="80" uuid="2b946dfa-c599-4ea2-873b-d68073885475"/>
                    <subreportParameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="REPORT_RESOURCE_BUNDLE">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_RESOURCE_BUNDLE}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "Left.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
                <subreport isUsingCache="false">
                    <reportElement style="table" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="300" y="0" width="255" height="80" uuid="aa26fd8b-b945-4d61-b3c6-2019f1e2c779"/>
                    <subreportParameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="REPORT_RESOURCE_BUNDLE">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_RESOURCE_BUNDLE}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "Right.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Subreport on the left side, called Left.jasper:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.6.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.6.0  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Invoice" pageWidth="300" pageHeight="255" columnWidth="300" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" resourceBundle="InvoiceBundle" uuid="4328d8a4-e5d5-4d7d-9fba-b42407325799">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.5000000000000007"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="develop trunk"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <style name="table">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="DATEFORMAT" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT 'this is a short text' AS short_text]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="short_text" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="80" splitType="Stretch">
            <frame>
                <reportElement style="table" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="300" height="80" uuid="7688bc26-63fe-4013-b7dc-514f2f078be1"/>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="5" y="20" width="245" height="15" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="c71b1e9d-f637-4511-b304-ba5a9603331e"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="9"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{short_text}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Subreport on the right side, called Right.jasper:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.6.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.6.0  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Invoice" pageWidth="255" pageHeight="255" columnWidth="255" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" resourceBundle="InvoiceBundle" uuid="4328d8a4-e5d5-4d7d-9fba-b42407325799">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.5000000000000007"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="develop trunk"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <style name="table">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select 'This is a very long text, that makes the text field stretch.
This is a very long text, that makes the text field stretch.
This is a very long text, that makes the text field stretch.
This is a very long text, that makes the text field stretch.
This is a very long text, that makes the text field stretch.
This is a very long text, that makes the text field stretch.
This is a very long text, that makes the text field stretch.
This is a very long text, that makes the text field stretch.
This is a very long text, that makes the text field stretch.
' AS long_text]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="long_text" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="80" splitType="Stretch">
            <frame>
                <reportElement style="table" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="255" height="80" uuid="9402fe9b-072f-4d99-9686-eaf896fa5281"/>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="5" y="20" width="250" height="15" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="cf207ce1-909e-4e80-802b-7b8dcb22f05b"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="9"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{long_text}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: The different subreport will execute independently, hence each stretch to it's relative band, so no like this you can't achieve it, search for an alternative solution, for example in this example you could draw the box (bottom line) on the frame in main report (removing the bottom line in subreport) or as you stated have both fields in same subreport.

Comment: If both subreports are inside the same container can't you just instruct the small one to stretch relative to band, container or tallest object?
[stretch type](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/schema.reference.html#reportElement_stretchType)

Comment: @Gustavo AFIK since the text element is inside a subreport it will stretch only relative to components inside the subreport, hence in this case you could get it to stretch to band height. I don't think that even if you stretch subreport from outside (main report), this text element will increase size (since it's relative to it's report/components in it's report). If you can prove me wrong you will have my upvote!